# informatica scenario for replacing char

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have the following data

### Package

6-pack

5-pack

2x12-pack

3x14-pack

How to get below desired output

### Package

6

5

12

14

Please help me with this in informatica.

Answer (score 2):

Using Regular Expression:

```
REG_EXTRACT(input_field,'(\d*x?)(\d+)(-pack)',2)
```

Explanation:

- (\d*x?) - matches zero or more digits with optional 'x'
- (\d+) - matches one or more digits **[desired group]**
- (-pack) - matches '-pack'